# select single row from foreign table in left join

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I want to fetch the first row where foreign key match. I don't know how to select first row
where foreign key matches

**events table**

```
id   |  name 
----------------
 1   |  john
----------------
 2  |  Cat
```

**event_attendee table**

```
id   |  event_id | type
--------------------------
 1   |  1        | User
--------------------------
 2   |  1        | Local
--------------------------
 3   |  1        | User
--------------------------
 4   |  2        | User
--------------------------
 5   |  2        | User
```

**I want this result**

```
id   |  name    | event_id | type
------------------------------------
 1   |  John    | 1        | User
------------------------------------
 2   |  Cat     | 2        | User
```

**Tried**

```
select
a.*,
b.*
from
events as a
left join (
select
distinct
event_attendee.events_id,
event_attendee.type
from
event_attendee
left join events on
event_attendees.events_id = events.id
where
events.id = event_attendees.events_id
limit 1 

) as b on
a.id = b.events_id
```

**Problem**

It only works for the 1st row, for 2nd row its show empty

```
id   |  name    | type
------------------------------------
 1   |  John    | User
------------------------------------
 2   |  Cat     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a lateral join.  In Postgres, the syntax is:

```
select e.*, ea.*
from events e left join lateral
     (select ea.event_Id, ea.Type
      from event_attendee ea
      where ea.event_id = e.id
      order by ea.id
     ) ea
     on 1=1;
```

However, `distinct on` is a way to do this with no subqueries:

```
select distinct on (e.event_id) e.*, ea.*
from events e join
     event_attendee ea
     on ea.event_id = e.id
order by e.event_id, ea.id;
```

I would expect the lateral join to work better on larger tables, particularly with the correct indexes.

Comment: lateral join does not give the correct result. But **distinct on**  gives the desire output.
You can see the actual result example in my question. Thanks (Y)

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the rank and use it to filter 1st record:

```
select
t_.id, t_.name, t_.type
from
(
select a.*, b.type,
rank() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY b.id asc) rank_
from events a
left join event_attendees b
on 
a.id = b.events_id
) t_
where
t_.rank_ = 1
```

Comment: Please the fiddle url. Its working. [Fiddle URL] : (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=50692f6542d40d5401f58f1573c36b0c)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy with a `cross apply`:

```
select *
from events e
cross apply (
    select top (1) event_Id, Type
    from event_attendee ea
    where ea.event_id=e.id
    order by id
)x
```

Edit, alternative compatible method!

```
select e.*,ea.event_Id, (select type from event_attendee ea2 where ea2.id=ea.id ) Type
from (
    select Min(id) Id, event_id
    from event_attendee
    group by event_id
)ea
join events e on e.id=ea.event_id
```

Comment: why it gives error near apply, syntax error on or near "apply"

Comment: Yes unfortunately I didn't pay attention to your postgres tag - it needs slightly different syntax using `lateral join` - you already have that solution now. As an aside, I've edited above and added an alternative way of writing it using just a standard correlated subquery. Regards Stu.